# Push notification from Carriot to iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, iot

I am doing one of the IoT application which uses [Carriot SDK](https://www.carriots.com/) for data collection. I am also developing application on `iOS` to see the data present on carriot. 
       To display the data on device i am using [Carriot API's](https://www.carriots.com/documentation). Is there any way in which we can send push notification from Carriot to iOS ?

Answer (score 0):

From the Carriots Team:

Hi everyone,

Yes it is possible to send push notification from Carriots to mobile devices (iOs and Android). We don't have a tutorial on this, but we will create one soon.

It is possible to create a Listener in Carriots to connect to an external API like the one from Google (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) or a similar service like Pushbots ( https://pushbots.com/developer/api/1 )

Any of these services will let you send push notifications to iOs and Android.

Enjoy and good luck,

The Carriots Team

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply team Carriot.!!
             We are developing IoT application in which we are getting data from sensors. We mounted those sensors on arduino. We are continuously sending sensor data to carriot . Now our use case is once sensor data goes beyond the threshold value user device needs to get notified by push notification. So when can we expect the push notification tutorial or can you please tell steps in detail ?

Comment: We will put this tutorial on our TO-DO list. It will take us a few weeks to do it. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

Look for more info here:
 - If using Google: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream
 - If using Pushbots: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3YlqWWnI6s